# Show transient states do not communicate.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given $$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So $\{5\}$ is a recurrent class because $5$ is absorbing.

Let $A = \{2, 4\}$. Then $P_A$ is stochastic, so $A$ is closed. Since $p_{24}, p_{42} > 0$, we know $2 \leftrightarrow 4$. Since closed, all states communicate and finitely many states, $A$ is a recurrent class.

Since $p_{02}, p_{12}, p_{32} > 0$ we see $0, 1, 3 \rightarrow 2$ but $0, 1, 3 \notin A$. Since $A$ is closed, states $0$, $1$, and $3$ are all transient.

We see that column for state $3$ is all zero, so $p_{i3}^{(n)} = 0$ for all $n$. Therefore $\{3\}$ is a transient class.

**Here's my question. Are $0$ and $1$ together a class or are they separate classes? How do I show that?**

Comment: I am not following: if $0\to1$ and $1\to0$, the answer is yes, otherwise the answer is no. So, do you think $0\to1$ and $1\to0$?

Comment: The matrix says that $p_{01} =0$. So why do you say that $0 \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: "So why do you say that 0→1?" Did I say so? Where? Anyway, the fact that 0→1 and the fact that $p_{01}=0$ are not a contradiction in general. Come on! Study your own question...

Comment: I have studied this question at length. I can see that $p_{01}^{(n)} = 0$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4$. However, that proves nothing. Herein lies my question. Can I show $p_{01}^{(n)} = 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: Sure: simply draw the states with an arrow between $x$ and $y$ if and only if $p_{xy}\ne0$, and you will see right away what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the state transition diagram for the given transition probability matrix.
[image]

As you have observed, there are two closed communicating classes, viz. `{5}` and `{2,4}`. Hence, all these states are recurrent. The state `1` itself forms a communicating class, but the class is not closed. Hence, state`1` is a transient state. Similarly, the communicating class of state `0` contains only state `0` and it is non-closed. Therefore, state `0` is also a transient state. State `3` does not communicate even with itself. Such a state is called **non-return** state and is a transient state.